# How can I find the GUID of my graphics device?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, directx

How can I find the GUID of my DirectX/Direct3D graphics device in Windows 7? I need to put it in a registry entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the graphics device GUID your will first need to run the `dxdiag` tool.  You can run the tool by typing <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  Enter `dxdiag` in the box and hit "OK".

Once the tool is open select "Save All Information".  Save the text file somewhere like the desktop and then open it in a text editor.

You will see a section in the file called Display.  In the Display section find the "Device Identifier".  This should be the GUID you are looking for.

```
---------------
Display Devices
---------------
       Card name: My Card Name
       Manufacturer: My Card Corp

snip...

       WHQL Logo'd: n/a
       WHQL Date Stamp: n/a
--->   Device Identifier: {FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFF}
       Vendor ID: 0xFFFF
       Device ID: 0xFFFF
       SubSys ID: 0xFFFFFFFFF
       Revision ID: 0xFFFF
```

Comment: Oh. I was already in dxdiag, but i thought "Save All Information" would just save what i saw to a text file. Gotta try it though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the graphics card GUID? It can be obtained through Device Manager by right-clicking on the device, selecting *Properties* > *Details* tab, and selecting "Device Class GUID" from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: I was there, but I thought the device class was a GUID about what KIND of device (Graphics card, Mouse, Screen, ...) it is. I'll try this!